# class isn't picking up my CSS style

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS file which is being read fine as everything else is styled, so here is my style code for the element i'm trying to style

```
.big-html-area {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

and here is my element

```
@Html.WrappedTextAreaFor(x => x.Description, new { @class = "form-item-container textbox big-html-area" }, new { @class = "html-area" })
```

here is the source output
[image]

Why isn't it picking up the style?

Comment: Are you able to paste the source output HTML here please?

Comment: Show the right hand side of firebug, I doubt it's specificity

Comment: As the class is written in the HTML, and matched in the CSS, something must be overriding it. Can you share a link or create a JSFiddle with the HTML/CSS?

Comment: I'd guess that the `div` itself has been modified by one of the other CSS classes to become a `display: inline` or similar element. In that case, your settings for width/height will be ignored.

Comment: I looked at the CSS and yes it was getting over written by editor-wrapper which would set it to 200px, so I am now using form .big-html-area .editor-field but still getting the same size ? what screenshot did you want guys?

Comment: it would seem that the width and height are now being set, but I am using JHtmlArea and it seems to render it small first, then the box gets bigger, but the JHtmlArea doesn't refresh its size

Comment: Can you post your outputted HTML and post your CSS please or create a JSFiddle with your code. It's very hard to debug without seeing code and understanding what's happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, do this:

```
.big-html-area {
    width: 400px !important;
    height: 300px !important;
}
```

Styles being applied? Good! That means your selector is valid. Styles not being applied? Then your selector needs to be reworked.

If your styles are being applied with `!important`, all you need to do is fiddle with the specificity of the selector so that its styles will win out against any other mutually exclusive styles. if you are handy with your browser's developer tools, you can identify what selector is applying any styles that are interfering with your intentions.

Start by applying an ID to your selector, that will win out over any other non-important selector without an ID:

```
#someId .big-html-area{
     width:400px;
     height: 300px;
}
```

You may need to keep adjusting the specificity of your selector until it is more specific than other selectors:

ref: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

However, if the competing style is being applied via javascript, then it is being applied inline which makes it more specific than anything applied in a stylesheet. Sad panda:

```
 <form class="big-html-area" style="width:1000px;height:500px">
```

In this case, your only option would be to use the `!important` keyword as indicated above to overrule specificity entirely. This is one of the rare situations I would let `!important` into a production CSS.

Comment: This tip is a lifesaver.